# Implementing dropzone in a form in ASP.net 404 error

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-core, dropzone.js

Currently I am trying to implement a dropzone in a pre-existing form using asp.net razor pages. My div containing the dropzone looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Add Files</label><br />
    <div runat="server" class="dropzone dz-clickable" id="myDropzone">
    </div>
</div>
```

and my js looks like this:

```
    Dropzone.options.myDropzone= {
    url: '/uploads/image',
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 5,
    maxFiles: 5,
    maxFilesize: 1,
    acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
    addRemoveLinks: true

}
```

With this I get a 404 error even though I have set up a folder in the wwwroot folder called uploads and I'm still getting the error. I want these files to be uploaded to this directory so I can process them when the submit button is pressed. Currently I am able to send the files to the C# file by calling `Request.Form.Files` just by using `<input type="file" />` but I haven't been able to get dropzone to work in a similar way.

Comment: There seems to be multiple problems here. which tutorial are you trying to follow?

Comment: `url: '/uploads/image',` will go to  `localhost:xxx//uploads/image`,rather than go to `/wwwroot//uploads/image`,you can upload files in the action which route is `localhost:xxx//uploads/image`.